# Why is my localhost trying to connect to my online site?

Tags: php, localhost, dreamweaver

I have an interesting problem, I am developing my site and save all the files on my local drive edit them with adobe Dreamweaver, and once approved I push it to my online server with Dreamweaver FTP client and once I start using PHP I uploaded it right away to my online server and test it on my real website.

But I change my mind and would like to run it locally, so I installed xampp and transferred the whole folder to the htdocs folder and tried viewing my folder, and for some reason, I was redirected to my online website...

**Any help on how to fix that and why this happened??**

Note: I assigned the current folder in Dreamweaver as my site when I upload it to my online server.

I am not sure what's causing this so I am not sure what details to include, if you need any more info I will share it here.

*Waiting for your helpful answer!!*

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. Maybe there's code that redirects if the server isn't XYZ?! Try searching your whole project for the domain it's redirecting to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @brombeer I search my entire folder and found an htaccess redirecting to my online page.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and by removing it it worked